# MYSQL Subselect in where clause

Tags: mysql, database, subquery

I'm breaking my head on this simple peace of code, that doesn't want to work, and I can't think of any other solution...

Could you please help to make it work?

```
SELECT chart FROM chart WHERE (select count(user_id) FROM users join charts ON
user_id=charts.UID and charts.chart=chart WHERE INET_NTOA(user_ip)='127.0.0.1')=0;
```

There are 3 tables involved with the following columns:

```
chart(
chart int(5)
);

charts(
UID int(11),
chart int(5)
);

`users` (
`user_id` int(11),
`user_ip` int(10)
);
```

The point is that the 'chart' column from first select should be passed to subquery to charts.chart= chart, but instead the subquery ends up comparing with itself i.e. chart=chart - always true.

I know it wont work like that... but I can't think of any other way really. Is there any way at all to the thing that I'm trying to do?

EDIT 1:
Basically I need a reverse selection:

```
  select chart.chart from chart join charts on chart.chart=charts.chart join users
  on user_id=charts.UID and INET_NTOA(user_ip)='127.0.0.1';
```

This query returns charts that are tagged by user with given ip, eg: 1, 4,5, 9.
But I need to select the ones that are not tagged instead, that is: 2,3,6,7,8,10 and so on...

EDIT 2:
I'm looking for some sort of negative join now. I think this would do, but I'm clueless how to use it. Meanwhile making some research...

Comment: So...... Any Ideas? I'm clueless at this point...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT c.chart FROM chart c
LEFT JOIN
( SELECT cn.chart FROM chart cn
  JOIN charts cs ON cn.chart = cs.chart
  JOIN users u ON u.user_id = cs.UID
  WHERE user_ip = 2130706433 ) charts_localhost
ON c.chart = charts_localhost.chart
WHERE charts_localhost.chart IS NULL
```

Note that instead of `INET_NTOA(user_ip)='127.0.0.1'` it's much better to use

`user_ip = 2130706433` which is equivalent but also index friendly.

Comment: Wow, I would never think of it nor do I understand what does _localhost do! But it's working! :) Thanks!
I'm using INET_NTOA though, because istead of 127.0.0.1 there should be '$_server['remote_addr']'.

Comment: It's just an alias for a subquery in parenthesis. If it's not just localhost ip but still constant for the query use `user_ip = INET_ATON( $server['remote_addr'] )` condition.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using aliases?

`select a.chart from chart a where (select count(user_id) from users join charts on
user_id=charts.UID and charts.chart=a.chart where INET_NTOA(user_ip)='127.0.0.1')=0;`

I don't know if it works in MYSQL, but I think it would work in MSSQL and Oracle.

Comment: Well I tried aliases but it says unknown column... basically it checks the where clause before it selects anything, so it cannot see it.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's a naming problem... Try doing this :

```
SELECT c.chart FROM chart c
WHERE (
    SELECT COUNT(u.user_id) FROM users u
    INNER JOIN charts ch
     ON u.user_id = ch.UID 
     AND ch.chart = c.chart
    WHERE INET_NTOA(user_ip)='127.0.0.1'
       ) = 0;
```

Comment: yeah I thought of it too, but it says: ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'c.chart' in 'on clause', so it wont work like that ... :(

Answer (score 0):

You can filter using a where select clause:

```
SELECT TS.*, T.* 
FROM tbl_teams as T
LEFT JOIN tbl_teamstats TS 
    ON TS.tbl_teams_id = T.id
WHERE 
TS.id = (
        SELECT TS.id FROM tbl_teamstats TS 
        WHERE TS.tbl_teams_id = T.id
        ORDER BY TS.id DESC
        LIMIT 1
    )
```